# Iterative splitting and indexing - r

Tags: r

I need to perform operations on split parts of a vector obtained by iteration.

Let's say I have a vector of length 25. I need intervals `d` from this vector where `d = s/p` where `p` varies from 1 to n.
for instance, when `p = 2`, `s` splits into two `d` intervals on each of which I need to perform certain operations. How do I call these split intervals? I tried following:

```
s<- c(1:25)
```

To split `s`, I can use the following function:

```
 chunk <- function(x, n) split(x, sort(rank(x) %% n))
```

However this function does  not allow splitting in iteration. e.g

```
for(i in 1:3){
 m[i]<- chunk(1:20,i)
 }
```

However this method doesn't work. Please help.

Regards,

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what exactly you're aiming to do with the output of `chunk()`, but for starters, you may have better luck if `m` is a list of the appropriate length, and you assign to it via `m[[i]] <- ` instead.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want. Do you want to split the vector into `n` smaller vectors?

Comment: @Manuja You are iterating from 1 to 3. Why 1? Change 1 any number more than 1 and it should work. I am not sure what is `m` though.

Comment: @joran , thanks man. It helped.

Comment: @YOLO m would store the output of split vector as list.

Comment: If  you used `m = lapply(1:3,chunk,x=1:20)` you would get a list with three elements like what you're aiming for, but with improved performance.